# Laravel blade components, nested attributes not forwarding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple component:

`<x-component something="new" />`

Inside component.blade.php I have:

`<x-another some="other" {{ $attributes }} />`

Inside another.blade.php I have:

`{{ $attributes }}`

What I expect to output:

`some="other" something="new"`

Instead:

`something="new"`

Is this expected behaviour? Is there something I'm missing in order to forward all attributes?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I think I have the same issue